# Content disposition link conflict

Tags: .htaccess, modx, content-disposition, modx-evolution

I use MODx Evolution and I included into my htaccess file the following:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.jpg$">
      Header append Content-Disposition "attachment;"
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.jpeg$">
      Header append Content-Disposition "attachment;"
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch "\.png$">
      Header append Content-Disposition "attachment;"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

I have a download button for each image that can be downloaded, like this:

```
<div class="box download-box">
                        <a class="button" href="[*template-variable-image*]">Download</a>
```

The above code works perfectly.

Now I've added another button for users to see the image in full scale in a separate browser tab with this code:

```
<h2 class="thumb-caption"><span data-href="[*template-variable-image*]" target="_blank">PREVIEW</span></h2>
```

Now when the user clicks "PREVIEW" the content disposition attachment box appears for download. How can I get the "PREVIEW" to show the preview of the image the way I planned and NOT the content download box???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a HTML than a MODX question. A lot of modern browsers know the [download attribute](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) in the a tag.

So throw away the .htaccess additions and use

```
<a class="button" href="[*template-variable-image*]" download>Download</a>
```

You could also use javascript for this and catch all browsers. John Culviner has written a nice jQuery plugin [jquery-file-download](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/) for this.